# Allow SSH into server connected to OpenVPN

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, openvpn

I recently purchased an Ubuntu based (Ubuntu 16.04.1 Xenial) computer which I am using as a server to access files from work.

While the server is connected to OpenVPN though (to access the work network), I cannot connect to the server over SSH. This server is headless, so being able to connect over SSH is necessary to use it.

Actually, I can SSH into the server even when it's connected to OpenVPN, but only when I am on the same network as the server - I can't connect remotely. This probably means that the SSH return packets are being routed over the VPN.

How can I configure the firewall on the server to allow SSH sessions?

Edit

This might clear something up:
Me -> Server -> OpenVPN

Comment: **1.** Can you log into your Ubuntu server when it is *not* on the OpenVPN? **2.** Do you need to access the OpenVPN only to connect to work pcs, or also to navigate to non-work-related sites? The answer to your question depends on your replies to the  above.

Comment: Can you ping your server from the machine you try to connect with SSH?

Comment: The question is not clear. what is connected to what, and what do you want to do. Do you want to have a openvpn server at work to connect too and ssh to the openvpn server.

Answer (score 3):

The server-side probably has "redirect-gateway" enabled. This means that when your OpenVPN client (your Ubuntu server) connects, it's default route is changed to redirect all outgoing IP traffic over the VPN.

You can confirm this by comparing your routing table when the VPN connection is offline to what it looks like when your VPN is online:

route -n

Pay particular note to your default (0.0.0.0/0) route.

You have a couple of options:

1. Add a static route on your Ubuntu server specifically for your remote IP address (even if this isn't a realistic option because it varies, you may want to do this to test diagnosis).

   sudo route add -net /32 gw
2. Re-configure the OpenVPN server to be explicit about what networks are reachable via it/the VPN and get the redirect-gateway option disabled on it.
3. Mark packets destined for your Ubuntu server and route them using your typical default gateway like described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/301364
4. Do something like option 3, but specific to just handling 22/tcp (SSH) traffic perhaps.